# Critical section with state variable using Interlocked.Exchange

Tags: c#, locking, critical-section, interlocked

I have a critical section that I'm trying to protect using `Interlocked.Exchange` on a member variable (`int _state`). This is the code:

```
if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref _state, 1) == 0)
{
    // *** Danger zone ***
    try
    {
         // Do something
    }
    finally
    {
         _state = 0;
    }
}
```

`_state` is also read elsewhere to determine state, so this is required.

My concern is that should an exception occur in the "Danger zone", `_state` will never be set to 0 and the critical section will never be able to be entered again.

Is there a better way of doing this while still being able to set a state variable? Should I be using a double lock pattern?

Comment: And why not put danger zone inside try block?

Comment: See docs on lock: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement

Comment: @Evk There is no C# code there. My point is that an exception could occur there caused by intermediary code placed there by the compiler.

@AdamBenson Of course I'm aware of `lock`, but how does that help with the `_state` variable I mentioned given that `_state` is being used to control access to the critical section, and is read elsewhere? This is why I'm using `Interlocked.Exchange`, to at least read/write it atomically.

Comment: Not sure you should care about such things. Take for example basic `lock`. It is used like `if (Monitor.TryEnter(myLock, ref lockTaken) try {...} finally {...}`, and no one thinks that lock won't be released if exception is thrown in the same "danger zone".

Comment: @Evk Good point. Thanks for the comparison. If C# doesn't care, then I don't. ;)